# React Form Submission - Fields Always Empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm struggling to figure out how we're supposed to handle submitting a form in React. First time user, failed hard so far.

The data in the form is always empty meaning the json is also empty.

As far as I can tell from all the examples I've read this should be working.

My component is a simple registration component:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { PropsType } from './Routes';
import { Form, Col, FormGroup, ControlLabel, FormControl, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

export default class Register extends React.Component<PropsType, any> {

    public constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);

        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    public render() {

        return <Form horizontal onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} id={'reg-form'}>
                   <FormGroup controlId="formHEmail">
                       <Col componentClass={ControlLabel} sm={2}>
                           Email
                       </Col>
                       <Col sm={10}>
                           <FormControl type="email" placeholder="Email" />
                       </Col>
                   </FormGroup>

                   <FormGroup controlId="formPassword">
                       <Col componentClass={ControlLabel} sm={2}>
                           Password
                       </Col>
                       <Col sm={10}>
                           <FormControl type="password" placeholder="Password" />
                       </Col>
                   </FormGroup>

                   <FormGroup controlId="formConfirmPassword">
                       <Col componentClass={ControlLabel} sm={2}>
                           Confirm Password
                       </Col>
                       <Col sm={10}>
                           <FormControl type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" />
                       </Col>
                   </FormGroup>

                   <FormGroup>
                       <Col smOffset={2} sm={10}>
                           <Button type="submit">Create Account</Button>
                       </Col>
                   </FormGroup>
               </Form>;
    }

    public handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        console.log('Register.POST');

        console.log('TARGET IS: ' + e.target);

        const data = new FormData(e.target);
        console.log(data);

        const json = JSON.stringify(data);
        console.log(json);

        fetch('/api/account/register', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json',                  
            },
            body: json,
        }).then(res => {
            console.log(res);
        });
    }
}
```

How can I get the values from the form into json data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add `value` to `FormControl` to let it know what value to render.

And add `onChange` to let it know what to do when DOM input change. Here we update `state.email` value so `FormControl` will receive new `value` prop and rerender with updated email. You can do the same with other inputs.

We also add `name` prop which is value of `event.target.name` to know which field to update, so we don't have to create duplicated handle function for each input.

```
public constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {}
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleEmailChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}

public handleChange (event) {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
}

public handleSubmit() {
    console.log(this.state); // Your json data is here
}

public render() {

        return <Form horizontal onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} id={'reg-form'}>
                   <FormGroup controlId="formHEmail">
                       <Col componentClass={ControlLabel} sm={2}>
                           Email
                       </Col>
                       <Col sm={10}>
                           <FormControl
                               type="email"
                               name="email"
                               placeholder="Email" />
                               value={this.state.email}
                               onChange={this.handleChange}
                       </Col>
                   </FormGroup>
               </Form>
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, This got me on track.  I had to also change my submit code to use the state like this - `const json = JSON.stringify(this.state);` The `FormData(e.target)` approach just would not work.